# Any recommendations for streaming audio from grails app?

Tags: grails, audio, groovy, streaming

I'm trying to stream an audio file from a grails app. The audio file is most likely to be in mp3 format.

I couldn't find any examples or hints on the net, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SoundManager](http://www.grails.org/plugin/sound-manager) plugin might be useful. I've never used it personally.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. It doesn't do exactly how I want it to work at the moment, but it'll do for now.